# Hibernate Envers SQL auditing

Tags: sql, hibernate, hibernate-envers, auditing

I was wondering if anyone had succeeded in auditing a native query (SQL) with Hibernate Envers? I know this is probably just wrong, but it would spare me a lot of refactoring time.

Cheers

Nick

Comment: @adamw any thoughts on that?

Comment: What do you mean auditing an SQL query?

Comment: I mean executing an insert using SQL (using executeUpdate() for instance) instead of hibernate.persist/save() ...

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that would work. I've tried insert/delete statements but they didn't trigger the envers audit.

Comment: That's exactly my point. I want to know if someone already came up with some workaround, cause Envers is not prepared to handle this.

Answer (score 3):

I just want to leave  my thoughts here so others might benefit when they choose to Envers. We tried Hibernate envers in one our recent project and it did not work out. Below are the reason

1. Hibernate Envers captures the Audit information only when the updates happen through Persistence Context.
2. We did not like one audit table for each entity. It was too much schema pollution.
3. We have lot of batch jobs and data synchronization scripts that updates data directly using sql queries. Any update that is happening outside the persistence context will not be captured in these Hibernate ENvers created Audit tables.

SO we went with Database trigger appraoach with just only one AUDIT table which will capture the table_name, column_name, primary_key, old_value and new_value. It worked for us.